# font awesome not loading on one specific machine in firefox 25

Tags: firefox, font-awesome

Font awesome is loading perfectly on my machine on all the browsers and on  my colleague's machines.

But on one specific persons laptop it is not working on firefox25. It is showing square blocks with some random thing instead of icons. I am not sure how should I solve that. If some one could please guide it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [external CDN](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/#bootstrapcdn) link for embedding your fonts or fix your web server's [CORS access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25923207/2817112).